# Hide GET parameters

Tags: php, url, get

I would like to hide the ID GET parameter from my URL after load, yet retain data.

Basically, I'm giving the option for users to make a private page public, but don't want people to be able to see the ID of the Watchlist, because they could then just change the number and see anyone's Watchlists, rather than just the one specific Watchlist which the user has decided to make public.

The original button to make the Watchlist public looks like so:

```
<a href="watchlist-download.php?id=<?php $watchlist_id; ?>" 
   class="btn btn-primary btn-block download-pdf" title="Download Watchlist PDF">
   <i class="icon-share icon-white"></i> Share Watchlist
</a>
```

The Watchlist ID is required to populate the resulting page, however (so, for example, the page returns back a list of items associated with the Watchlist ID in the database), so the ID would need to be in the URL (or, it would need to be *somewhere*) to fetch back the correct content, but the user shouldn't be able to see it in the URL.

I'm not sure if this is actually achievable or not. If you need any more information/code snippets, just ask! Not sure what people will need to be able to solve this, so if you let me know what you need/what's relevant (if anything!), I'll post it up.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Use `$_POST` instead?

Comment: @Evan even if you use POST, users can still make requests with arbitrary IDs. You will need to check to make sure the user is allowed to view the page they're trying to. You'll need a database.

Comment: @sachleen I agree, but POST will at least *hide* the values like the OP wants

Comment: I would use some sort of a hash instead of the id, it's a common way to create a "public link".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another suggestion would be to use a random hash, for example md5 which is linked to your watchlist. You can just generate one when creating the watchlist.

To generate a unique md5 hash in php you could use:

```
$unique_hash = md5(uniqid(rand(), TRUE));
```

Assuming you have a database table with your watchlists:

```
id_watchlist | name | hash
```

And then for example the following contents:

```
1 | watch 1 | 41ad0f218d400e4a1bcfdf9e762163e7
2 | watch 2 | e82fd1f16c23fd04e7893afc41e6a358
```

Then you use the hash instead of the id to get the coresponding watchlist.

```
<a href="watchlist-download.php?hash=<?php $watchlist_hash; ?>" 
   class="btn btn-primary btn-block download-pdf" title="Download Watchlist PDF">
   <i class="icon-share icon-white"></i> Share Watchlist
</a>
```

For example:

`http://www.example.com/watchlist_download.php?hash=e82fd1f16c23fd04e7893afc41e6a358`

So in the end it's not possible to just change the id in the url and the watchlist is still accessible with a normal link.

Comment: Marcel, the IDs of Watchlists are incremental when creating a new Watchlist. Is there any way to dynamically generate just a hash sequence on creation of the Watchlist? If so, this looks exactly like what I'm looking for!

Comment: I've added a possible sollution in php.

Comment: @AlexRyans You can use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` and there is also [`parse_url`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.parse-url.php). But I would write a litte script to update the existing entries and add a hash to them.

Comment: @MarcelGwerder Thank you. I've managed to sort through it as I mentioned in the previous comment (I accidentally deleted the comment - sorry!), but I'm not too sure how I'd go about writing this script to update existing entries? Where would I execute this script? Sorry for my contant questioning - I'm a relative PHP novice, learning pretty much as I go along.

Comment: You could just create a php file on your server with a loop that updates the existing entries. Maybe also with a short timeout between  the loops because uniqid is using the milliseconds to get a unique id (but I'm not sure if really necessary). Run it once and then remove it again.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like you want to use `$_POST` instead of `$_GET`

```
<form method="post" action="watchlist-download.php">
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $watchlist_id ?>"
    <button type="submit" value="Go">Share Watchlist</button>
</form>
```

To respond to your other issue, making sure that the user at hand can't see other's videos, you're going to need to create a database, each user will have a *unique* userID, and when a user goes to a video you will query the database to ensure that the viewed video is associated with the current user. Most likely you will have a table called `user_video` which will store `user_id` along with a `video_id`

Comment: Thanks, Evan! For the time being, I'm quite happy with just hiding the values - this is for a uni project and deadline day is fast approaching!

Comment: @AlexRyans Well if you just want to hide the values then use `$_POST` and call it a day

Answer (score 0):

If you put `id` anywhere in the page (whether or not in the URL), its not private anymore. The best way to secure URL parameters is to generate a random hash and save the URL in database against that hash.

Your watchlist URL will look something like `/watchlist-download.php?get=e7b3418ab97e75deade429cb8da1dce4` and then lookup the hash in the database and fetch the original URL, parse it internally and give the viewer what it wants.

If this hash is generated only on demand of the content owner, it will also prevent CSRF attacks.